# No output is shown and the terminal window is not opening

Tags: java, bluej

I have created a program to replace a SMS abbreviation with it's full form. Suppose 'R' with 'Are' and 'U' with 'You' without using replace() directly. But I don't know why the terminal window is not showing up after I execute the program.

```
`import java.util.*;
public class SMS
{
public static void main()
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    String s=sc.nextLine();
    s=s.trim();
    s=" "+s+" ";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)==' '&&s.charAt(i+2)==' ')
        {
            if(s.charAt(i+1)=='R')
            {
                String temp=s.substring(i);
                String temp1=s.substring(i+1,s.length());
                s=temp+"Are"+temp1;
            }
            if(s.charAt(i+1)=='U')
            {
                String temp=s.substring(i);
                String temp1=s.substring(i+1,s.length());
                s=temp+"You"+temp1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

}`

Comment: try debugging your code

Comment: Hi, you need to accept a string array as a parameter of a main method. E.g. "public static void main(String[] args)"

Comment: This code may throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`